# группировка полей yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

```
return $this->hasMany(Reportcard::className(), ['category_id' => 'id'])->select(['count(received_person_id) as count'])->where(['between', 'accepted_date', "$time1", "$time2" ])->groupBy(['received_person_id']);
```

как вытащить группированные поля(received_person_id), через count не получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Либо ознакомьтесь с [этой частью документации](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#selecting-extra-fields), либо используйте альтернативный пример ниже

```
public function getYourRelation () {
         return $this->hasMany(Reportcard::className(), ['category_id' => 'id'])->->where(['between', 'accepted_date', "$time1", "$time2" ])->groupBy(['received_person_id']);

    }

    public function getYourRelationCount () {
        return $this->getYourRelation()->count();
    }

    echo $model->yourrelationcount;
```